# Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine "_cake_core_" is not properly configured cakephp AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cakephp

I am getting following error: using `cakephp`, `aws`.

> Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-gb' to
>   File cache in /var/www/html/myApp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 328
>
> Warning: /var/www/html/myApp/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable
>   in /var/www/html/myApp/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line
>   385
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache
>   engine "_cake_core_" is not properly configured. Ensure required
>   extensions are installed, and credentials/permissions are correct' in
>   /var/www/html/myApp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:186 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/myApp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151):
>   Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1
>   /var/www/html/myApp/app/Config/core.php(383):
>   Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2
>   /var/www/html/myApp/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72):
>   include('/var/www/html/i...') #3
>   /var/www/html/myApp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(431):
>   Configure::bootstrap(true) #4
>   /var/www/html/myApp/app/webroot/index.php(95):
>   include('/var/www/html/i...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/myApp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 186

**NOTE :** `tmp` folders have full permission(777), yet getting the same error, please advise?

I have gone through 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/gKFJf6mK6qk
also.

Comment: You have writable permissions on the child directories too? On `tmp/cache` and `tmp/cache/persistent` (if they exist already). It's definitely just a file permissions issue.

Comment: all sub folders are present and i have given full permission to all sub folders.

Comment: i have doubt if the apache service user is root and i don't have  root access ,(am user1 with less privilege) if me (user1) provide 777 to folders it will be valid for Apache service (root service-/usr/sbin/httpd) . Sorry if the question is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with server configuration, Firewall should be disable on the server to access 777 folder by anonymous users.